# Problema con el apache Xampp

Tags: php, postgresql, apache, cakephp, cakephp-bake

Tengo que utilizar PostgreSQL para un trabajo  y habilito el **pdo** y la extensión de postgres en el archivo `php.init` e igual no me conecta con las tablas , me doy cuenta que en la consola coloco el comando :

```
php -m
```

No aparece tampoco en los módulos el postgres , en :

```
php -v
```

Dice que la version es la 5.5.12 y accedo al phpInfo dice 7.1.4 . espero puedan ayudar tengo Windows 10

Comment: ¿Reinicias el servidor Apache cada vez que modificas el `php.ini`? ¿Estás seguro de que no tienes mas de una versión de `PHP` instalada? ¿Controlaste que en las variables de entorno (`echo %PATH%`) este la ruta correcta al `xampp y php`?

Comment: si reinicio el apache cada vez que he modifico el el archivo **php.ini** , con respecto yo tenia otra version **vieja ** de xampp y la actualice . y en la variables de entorno del sistema ** PATH**  coloque esto C:\xampp\php